# How can i overlap two parts in plt.hist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

[image: The image is here]

my code:

```py
plt.hist(all_loss[0][-1][clean_idx].numpy(), bins=20,density=True,alpha=0.5,stacked=True,facecolor="cornflowerblue",label='clean')
plt.hist(all_loss[0][-1][noisy_idx].numpy(), bins=20, density=True,alpha=0.5,stacked=True,facecolor="pink",label='noisy')
```

The picture I get:
[image: The picture is here]

Answer (score 1):

You need to include both datasets in the same call to `plt.hist`. Note that you likely also do *not* want to set `stacked=True`. Instead, I have set `histtype='stepfilled'`, and use a transparency setting, `alpha=0.5`, to show the overlap. If for some reason, you don't want identical bins for the two datasets, you can use `bins=[10, 20]`, for example (as I've done for the colour settings and the labels).

There are actually multiple examples the [Matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/histogram_multihist.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-histogram-multihist-py) of histograms (although none shows a filled overlap with transparancy; that is sadly missing).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = rng.normal(15, 5, 200)
b = rng.normal(20, 5, 200)

plt.hist([a, b], 20, color=['cornflowerblue', 'pink'], histtype='stepfilled', density=True, alpha=0.5, label=['clean', 'noisy'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

I would also suggest to have a look at the [Seaborn `hist` function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html). Seaborn extends the Matplotlib functionality, and often has this kind of graphs built-in.

Comment: You can make two calls to hist without a problem, but you probably want to have the same bins in each one ie bins = np.arange(25)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no problem with the `hist` function. It's wrong with my **input data**. To overlap two parts, two calls are OK! @0 0

Comment: @QiweiWang Well, if your data is incorrect, than I don't understand your problem, and can't help you.